# What is "matter"?

Tags: reference-request, ontology, philosophy-of-physics, substance, matter

How do philosophers define matter?

Maybe we could say that matter is made out of fundamental particles. However, that ignores dark matter and energy. But even if we ignore this, what are fundamental particles? They are entirely defined by their mathematical properties such as mass, charge, and spin. So it seems particles are just [bundles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_theory) of these properties.

Yet, it seems matter is not just mathematical structure, it feels like there is some "stuff".

Are there any books or articles about this topic?

Comment: It is a quite old topic: [Form vs. Matter](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/form-matter/): if "mathematical structure" is *form* what is the *matter* (the "stuff")? What is left when we forget about the "structure"?

Comment: suggest you post this on the physics stack exchange. -NN

Comment: The concept was ambiguous already in antiquity, with Democritus's atoms vs Aristotle's "pure potentiality", and underwent major transformations since. There is no consensus view and volumes written on different conceptions, e.g. [The Concept of Matter](https://archive.org/details/conceptofmatter00mcmu/page/n13/mode/2up). Even the [survey up to Newton's time](https://sites.google.com/site/encyclopediaofideas/science-and-nature/matter-changing-concepts-of-matter-from-antiquity-to-newton) runs pretty long. You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: This ["old joke"](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/how-to-convey-the-meaning-of-mathematical-maturity#comment8485_1403) is piquant

Comment: See [Language games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_game_(philosophy)). In philosophy matter is whatever we think it is. For a scientific definition of matter you would have to ask on the physics stack exchange, since matter is a physical concept.

Comment: @timtam: That is not an accurate summary of language games. Intersubjectivity is not collective subjectivity. For instance cultural realities like money become something different to simply 'whatever we think it is' - we can't collectively wish away the real consequences of how we structure currencies.

Comment: @CriglCragl Yes, I think you're right. But money would still be whatever we think it means. If I think of money as the materialistic entity such as coins that we exchange for other goods then that's what money is in my mind, if I think of it as the capitalistic system then that's what money is in my mind. "Money" is a word. I think from a philosophical point of view the question "What is matter?" is the same question as "What is a donut?". And I think the OP is more interested in the baker's answer than in the philosopher's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're essentially right that

> particles are just bundles of properties

except that it's not   **"are"**,   it's more precisely   **"are described by"**,   which I think is a big philosophical *"distinction **with** a difference"* that's at the root of your question. You can never say what anything **"is"**, *per se*, except by reference to some other thing (or things) that already **"is"**. Otherwise, all you can do is describe its observable properties.

And the best mathematical description of a particle (or of anything) is a "complete state" (aka "pure state"), i.e., values for a maximal set of consistent (simultaneously measurable) observables. See (I'd highly recommend, though it involves some requisite math), *e.g.,* Chapters 5 and 6 of https://fdocuments.us/download/jauch-foundations-of-quantum-mechanics for a detailed discussion. So, yeah, that description of a "system" (or an "object", or your "matter") is a "bundle of properties", so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue matter in the modern sense, is the result of the journey of unification physics has been on. And that is better thought of as finding a common language, rather than as getting at an ontological unity or sameness: [Is the idea that "Everything is energy" even coherent?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/85899/is-the-idea-that-everything-is-energy-even-coherent/85950#85950)

Causality is deeply suspect, and rapidly frays when you start to pull at it's threads, including whether anything is ever really seperate. Discussed here: [Is the idea of a causal chain physical (or even scientific)?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70930/is-the-idea-of-a-causal-chain-physical-or-even-scientific/72055#72055)

I would suggest reading about Quantum Field Theory, in which particles are excitations of fields found everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

> How do philosophers define matter?

No previous answers address the point of view of philosophy, so, I feel compelled to answer.

Scientifically, the term *matter* has multiple definitions, some of which are mentioned on previous answers. But *that's not the philosophical perspective*.

Philosophically, let's say that there are two main loosely divided realms of existence:

- The metaphysical realm, essentially, what exists in the mind. Some elements here are the result of experience (e.g. the idea of the flavor of an apple), and some are pure rational/spiritual/emotional/etc. results(e.g. mathematics, God, ethics, feelings, law).
- The physical realm, essentially, what exists "outside" of each individual. Philosophically, matter would exist here. What differentiates this from the previous is that physical information is obtained by means of the senses.

So, for a simple answer, matter would be *what is perceived by means of the senses*.

*Substance* can be, in some cases, depending on the discipline or school of thought, equivalent to matter.

This classification is previously described as "loosely divided", because there are multiple interpretations of what can be physical and what is metaphysical. In general, it can be said that along time, philosophers have come to interpret existence progressively from what is purely physical to what is purely metaphysical.

As an example of early philosophy of matter, believe it or not, Plato's theory of *form and matter* would essentially propose that apples are some kind of materialization of circles, which would imply that form and matter would exist outside of our mind... horse-ideals would exist outside of our minds!

Around 1720, George Berkeley would propose that nothing would not exist physically, but that everything (ergo, matter) is produced inside our minds, by God.

Later, Kant proposed that matter would exist due to a teleological argument (that is, that our minds produce it for some subjective goal). I would say this is amazing, because it has a strong relation with early forms of the Systems Theory, where "systems are groups of parts interrelated performing towards for a goal". The "performing towards for a goal" was later removed and the concept remains as such in the modern theory. Considering that systems are ideals, the proximity of both concepts is remarkable.

Of course, since the *atomic theory*, things have changed a lot, and the concept of matter is not anymore addressed by philosophy, but moreover by science.

Remark that such configuration can perhaps be interpreted as science  *having diverged* from philosophy, which is quite risky for the development of knowledge. Perhaps the main conflict here is this: scientific realism (the perspective that currently and predominantly sustains science) proposes that things (ergo, matter) exist independently of any human reason, whereas multiple remarkable philosophers propose that things *don't exist* outside of reason. That implies a complete divergence about how matter is currently understood in philosophy and in science.

But apparently, quantum mechanics is producing a switch back of perspective towards a modern philosophical approach (try googling for "Kant quantum mechanics").

Answer (score 0):

### Ousia, Hyle, Substantia, and Materia

There are two philosophical terms related to the modern day conception of matter that are worth reviewing: [Gr. hyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hylomorphism) and [Gr. ousia or L. substance (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/substance/).

From WP:

> Hylomorphism is a philosophical doctrine developed by the Ancient Greek philosopher Aristotle, which conceives every physical entity or being (ousia) as a compound of matter (potency) and immaterial form (act), with the generic form as immanently real within the individual.[2](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/substance/) The word is a 19th-century term formed from the Greek words ὕλη (hyle: "wood, matter") and μορφή (morphē: "form").

From SEP:

> The philosophical term ‘substance’ corresponds to the Greek ousia, which means ‘being’, transmitted via the Latin substantia, which means ‘something that stands under or grounds things’. According to the generic sense, therefore, the substances in a given philosophical system are those things that, according to the system, are the foundational or fundamental entities of reality.

Philosophically, it is from these metaphysically complicated ideas that modern philosophers of physics have arrived at an understanding of [matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter):

> In classical physics and general chemistry, matter is any substance that has mass and takes up space by having volume. All everyday objects that can be touched are ultimately composed of atoms, which are made up of interacting subatomic particles, and in everyday as well as scientific usage, "matter" generally includes atoms and anything made up of them, and any particles (or combination of particles) that act as if they have both rest mass and volume. However it does not include massless particles such as photons, or other energy phenomena or waves such as light or heat.

While materials and form used to serve as the basis of matter, **mass in contemporary physics, that is anything that has mass and occupies space, is more than adequate for defining matter.**

### Aristotle's Thoughts on the Matter of Matter

We have an intuitive sense of matter in the form of [touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatosensory_system) and when we touch wood, for instance, there is something solid about it. To the some of the Pre-Socratics, the categories such as earth, wind, water, and fire were taken to be primitive, and there was much wrangling about what reality is and how to characterize things. The [ancient atomists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomism) latched onto the notion the believe that it didn't seem to make sense that you could take a piece of wood and divide it forever, and hence arrived at Gr. atomos, indivisible. Aristotle articulated his [four causes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_causes) which to answer a series of why-questions. In it, he noted a way to understand simple circumstances:

> A carpenter who wants to please a customer carves a statue of the client from wood.

**In this view, the material cause, wood would answer questions regarding what we would consider physical being, such as how the chisel and wood interact to give rise to the formal, efficient, and final causes.** The being of wood, then, allows us to discuss and predict situations with materials we can touch like wood, stone, bone, etc.

### Matter and Modern Physics

In modern philosophy, great deference is given to the weight of the philosophical claims alleged by physicists, who have a science of matter that is quite successful in moving matter around (landing Armstrong on the moon), and predicting how atoms form compounds and behave (think material science and physical chemistry). Albert Einstein stands next to Pythagoras in terms of famed equations with his [mass-energy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence). Besides making 'E equals mc squared' household science, he provided a theory to prove the existence of [mass dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity) and invoked the notion of [invariant mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass). Mass is an imputed property of matter, and thus modern notions of matter lean heavily upon the mathematics of [mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass) and energy.

**Thus, the concept of matter has moved from notions of being and substance of philosophical doctrines like hylomorphism and atomism, to being defined in terms of mass**, and one of the earliest researchers in this conceptual project was Gallilei who is famous from dropping matter, letting roll down ramps, and letting matter collide all the while advocating measurement. Newton later wrote of *quantitats materiae* and provided his mathematical laws. Thus, [natural philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_philosophy) moved in the direction of [mathematical physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_physics) and [operational definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_definition). Today, physicists refer to these ideas and explicate them with terms like [inertial mass, relativistic mass, and gravitational mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass#Inertial_vs._gravitational_mass). Jammer has an excellent introduction in his [*Concepts of Mass in Contemporary Physics and Philosophy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lYvz0_8aGsMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=jammer%20concepts%20of%20mass&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiuwbTOlNL-AhUOjIkEHQONA7gQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=jammer%20concepts%20of%20mass&f=false) (which is an easy read if you've had a calculus-based introductory sequence to physics including classical mechanics, E&M, and modern courses).

### Summary

So, the concept of matter has undergone notions starting with the ancient Greeks who intuitively related it to things and materials, to the natural philosophers who began to measure it as part of space and time, to the most modern notions that rely heavily on operational definitions of mass. Which is true, may be less important the question of which is most adequate for your worldview.