Philosophical reasoning suggests the law of conservation of energy is stupid and bound to fail
The law of conservation of energy believes that all natural phenomena can be decomposed into two processes——elastic collision and the conversion between kinetic energy and potential energy. Energy is conserved in both processes, so energy is conserved in any natural phenomenon.
Now, I will show that even without breaking its major premise (I don't actually believe it though), energy is still not necessarily conserved.
First, let's focus on the conversion between kinetic energy and potential energy. The best example is an apple (we simplify it to a mass point) moves vertically upward without being affected by any force other than gravity, reaches the highest point with a velocity of zero, "the kinetic energy has all converted into gravitational potential energy" and then falls back in a perfectly mirrored process. The apple returns to its original position with a velocity equal to its initial velocity, but in the opposite direction.
By the way, this is just a feature of uniformly accelerated rectilinear motion, and you can do the same trick without introducing extra entity called energy.
Back to the topic, let's then look at a similar but slightly more complicated situation. A bamboo dragonfly spins while slowly descending in the air. With just a little complexity, the law of conservation of energy fails laughably.
Just in case you misunderstood, bamboo dragonfly is a little copter. It is a toy that originated in East Asia and later spread to Europe. It is the ancestor of the helicopter.
As Joule's paddles in water experiments show, The kinetic energy gained by the water molecules comes from the rotational energy lost by the paddles. Similarly, when the bamboo dragonfly slowly descends, the main relative motion between it and the air is between the rotating blades and the air, rather than the overall downward motion relative to the air.
This means that almost all of the energy obtained by air molecules comes from rotational energy.
This further means that you cannot think that the reason why the actual translational kinetic energy of the bamboo dragonfly is much smaller than the change of gravitational potential energy is that the missing part of the translational kinetic energy is transferred to the air, because it is not happening and did not happen. This means that the total energy is no longer conserved.
I'm not a philosopher, but I do know some philosophy. However, I still need your professional knowledge.
If you are interested in physics thought experiments, there is a thought experiment of mine on this topic in this aviation chatroom, you can take a look.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This is 'pushing a personal philisophy', & just asking for opinions. And it's physics not philosophy. And the summary of your view seems to be that linear momentum isn't conserved because rotational momentum exists.
There are circumstances where energy is thought not to be conserved, like relating to the acceleration in expansion of the universe. You have substantial study to do before you can make sense of the issues, judging by your question.
Go read about the Least Action Principle.

I am not promoting a personal philosophy, and if Isaac Newton were alive, he would be standing with me.

I have now changed “opinion” to “professional knowledge". I am now asking for professtional knowledge.

I don't like to sound pretentious, but I have to prove that this is not a personal philosophy, so René Descartes, Galileo Galilei, John William Strutt, Ernst Mach, they are all on my side.

I don't know why you used the word momentum, I was talking about energy.

@Justaphysicsstudent: You clearly have no idea how little you know. It's comic that you think those figures didn't accept energy conservation. For elastic collisions, momentum is conserved, so it's a more precise statement of what you were saying. For inelastic collisions, some momentum goes in to processes like deformation & friction. In the UK we learn this about age 12.

Why are you still using the word "momentum"? You are talking about energy.

No matter how "little" I know, at least I know more than you about what is energy and what is momentum.

Seriously, if you want to mislead the general public reading this question, it won't work. People are not stupid. You claim that scientists who lived before the law of conservation of energy was established accepted it. (The first three of the five I listed) Don't be so unscrupulous.

In fact, each of the great men I listed has a focus. For example, Galileo represents the tradition of using thought experiments to obtain truth. Lord Rayleigh provided an accurate drag equation, and Ernst Mach did NOT believe in the conservation of energy. I suggest you read his "history and roots of the principle of the conservation of energy".

I wonder if the Emperor's New Clothes is included in your British student curriculum?

@Justaphysicsstudent: "Both Mach and Planck agreed that the law was valid, and they sought to purge energy of its anthropomorphic elements."https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1355219810000158 Newton held to Conservation of Momentum, & the concept of energy developed from there. For discussion on here: 'Is the idea that "Everything is energy" even coherent?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/85899/is-the-idea-that-everything-is-energy-even-coherent/85950#85950

But modern version of energy is very anthropomorphic.  It has always been this way.
the concept of energy developed from "living force" from Leibniz.

OMG, you didn't think Newton and Leibniz were the same person, did you?

@Justaphysicsstudent: What are you on about? The law of conservation of momentum, is implied by Newton's laws of motion. If two particles interact, as per Newton's third law the forces between them are equal in magnitude but opposite in direction.

I just want to point out to you that you are completely confusing momentum and energy, two completely different physical quantities.

Moreover, my question is about energy. Elastic collision is a special kind of collision. Momentum is conserved in any collision, but only in elastic collision is kinetic energy conserved. This is the definition of elastic collision.
